# RCP and external browser inclusion

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps-api-3, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm working on an RCP desktop application and I'm showing google map on the embedded `eclipse org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` class. Now, this class uses the default browser or whatever browser you specify.

The problem is when the app is going to be installed on the client machines, I have no guarantee that they would have anything higher than IE5 installed.

My question is, is there any way to include in my packaging a browser to ensure the compatibility of the libraries while it's transparent for the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to define a specific browser, SWT only offers to specify `SWT.WERBKIT` or `SWT.MOZILLA`. And both flags require their respective prerequisits.

See https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusewebkit for how to explicitly use WebKit or https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla for how to explicitly use Mozilla.

Hence, to my knowledge, your only option is to make sure that either of the two environments are installed on the respective platform when rolling out your application. At a first glance, installing the XULRunner (Mozilla) alongside your applications seems to be the easier option of th two.

But before going down that route I'd rather investigate how likely it actually is that your application will run on a platform that only has an outdated IE installed.